# Anyway to post message from hub class to another hub's javascript handler function

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have 2 hub classes: hubA and hubB.

In hubA I have a function that performs a task :

```
public void doSomething(string test){
    Clients[Context.ConnectionId].messageHandler(test);
}
```

I do not want this function to post back to  `hubA.messageHandler = function(){...}`  I want to be able to post a message back to `hubB.messageHandler = function(){...}`, but I am calling it from inside my `hubA` hub class.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain it a little better? Perhaps add some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both hubs are hosted in the same application you should just be able to use:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubB>()
```

Now the trick is, you appear to want to send a message to a specific client on HubB and the problem is that `Context.ConnectionId` for HubA will not be the same id for HubB. So what you need to do is have a mapping of some kind from ConnectionId to logical a user of some kind in both HubA and HubB. Then when you need to "bridge the gap" you do a lookup of the logical user from HubA by HubA's ConnectionId and then find the ConnectionId for HubB. At that point your code could look like this:

```
public void DoSomething(string test)
{ 
    // Get HubB's ConnectionId given HubA's ConnectionId (implementation left to you)
    string hubBConnectionId = MapHubAConnectionIdToHubBConnectionId(Context.ConnectionId);

    // Get the context for HubB
    var hubBContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubB>();

    // Invoke the method for just the current caller on HubB
    hubBContext.Clients[hubBConnectionId].messageHandler(test); 
}
```